# Can a Sequence of same input produce Different Result?

Tags: c++11, gcc, g++

**

> I am pretty sure a set of sequential commands with same input cant
> change it's output every time you run it

It might sound stupid . For example  while installing an application or bulding using Cmake , atleast for me , i would encounter different bugs each time i run the installer using the same system.
I guess i might have changed the cmake setting or the system settings but it feels so strange and i am totally paranoid about it.

**.

Comment: what are your input values ?

Comment: 2
3 2
1 2
5 3
1 2 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you never initialize *arr* but you use it to do *M=M-arr[i];* the behavior is undefined

out of that to use an array with a dynamic size is not recommended (ISO C++ forbids variable length array), allocate it in the heap